# rasterio: center crop geotiff, profiles and window_transform

Tags: image, gis, crop, geotiff, rasterio

I'm trying to do a simple center crop of as square geotiff using rasterio.

I crop the image using numpy, which works as expected, then update the image profile's height and width.

I also update the affine transform using `src.window_transform`, but I am doing something wrong. The affine transform ends up being incorrect.

My code is below. Can anyone tell me where I am messing up?
Thanks.

#### CODE:

```
import rasterio as rio

#
# FUNCTIONS
#
def get_image_and_profile(path):
    with rio.open(path) as src:
        profile=src.profile
        image=src.read()
    return image, profile


def image_write(im,path,profile):
    with rio.open(path,'w',**profile) as dst:
        dst.write(im)


def crop_image(image,crp):
    return image[:,crp:-crp,crp:-crp]


def crop_profile(profile,out_size,crp):
    win=(
        (crp,out_size+crp),
        (crp,out_size+crp))
    profile=profile.copy()
    profile.pop('transform',None)
    profile['width']=out_size
    profile['height']=out_size
    profile['affine']=src.window_transform(win)
    return profile



#
# CROP GEOTIFF
#
path='input.tif'
out_path='output.tif'
crp=92

im,profile=get_image_and_profile(path)
im=crop_image(im,crp)
profile=crop_profile(profile,im.shape[1],crp)
image_write(im,out_path,profile)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [window](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.windows.html) seems off, should be

> rasterio.windows.Window(col_off, row_off, width, height)

so:

> rasterio.windows.Window(crp, crp, img.shape[1](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.windows.html), img.shape[0])

Comment: so the docs say you can use `rasterio.windows.Window` as you described **or** a tuple  `((row_start, row_stop), (col_start, col_stop))` which is what i've done. that said, i'll try using the rasterio Window class and see if that works.

Comment: thanks!  rasterio.windows.Window worked.  i think i could have gotten the tuple to work as well.  turns out i was still on rasterio 0.36. i had to update to the latest (1.something) to use Window, but I did and it worked just fine.  thanks again

Comment: @brook: Glad it worked. You are right with the tuple, tuple though. What shape was your original image and clipped image? Seeing that you are using out_size[1] for both axis I guess it had the same number of rows and columns? If not that could have been the catch?

Comment: yep - i was using square images and doing a square cropping so i could simplify a bit.  thanks again.